# Excel VBA: Unable to Filldown from Date Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to find the most recent date in `column A` (the date in `column A` is determined by a formula) and filldown one row from the most recent date in `column A` through `column T`.

I am able to locate the most recent date in `column A` utilizing

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
```

but when I try to identify it in a range I am unsuccessful.

Below is the total of failing code:

```
Sub Find_Date()

Dim Max_date As Date

Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Max_date).End(xlDown).FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Once you get the `Max_date`, you must get the **row number** of the cell containing the value.  Then you can do the *fill-down*

Comment: Are you trying to fill across from Col A to Col T?

Answer (score 0):

Max_date gives you the actual date value, not the row value, so it doesn't work. You need to find a way to get the row number (i use worksheet match function below).
and since you got the date value already you can just use that value to populate col A to T

```
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

Max_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Max_date, Columns("A"), 0)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Max_Row & ":T" & Max_Row).Value = Max_date
```

Constraint - does not work when you have multiple identical max value in column A, the match function always goes for the first one only